# How to find a webelement that has 'checked' attribute in list of child WebElements through Selenium using Katalon Studio

Tags: selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait, katalon-studio

I have radio buttons that when either radio button is selected, it gets a `checked` attribute.

This is how the HTML looks:

[image: HTML]

My implementation of getting the descendant that has a `checked` attribute:

```
public TestObject getCheckedTestObjectFromParent(String parentID){
    WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()
    WebElement parentWebElement = driver.findElement(By.id(parentID))

    List<WebElement> children = parentWebElement.findElements(By.xpath(".//*"))
    println(children.size())
    for(int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++){
        TestObject childTestObject = getTestObjectFromWebElement(children[i])
        if(WebUI.verifyElementHasAttribute(childTestObject, 'checked', 10, FailureHandling.OPTIONAL)){
            return childTestObject
        }
    }
}
```

This is the helper method that I use for converting a `WebElement` to a `TestObject` :

```
public TestObject getTestObjectFromWebElement(WebElement element) {
        TestObject object = new TestObject()
        object.addProperty("xpath", ConditionType.CONTAINS, getXPathFromElement(element))
        return object
    }
```

Helper for getting `xpath` from `WebElement` :

```
protected String getXPathFromElement(WebElement element) {
        String elementDescription = element.toString();
        return elementDescription.substring(elementDescription.lastIndexOf("-> xpath: ") + 10, elementDescription.lastIndexOf("]"));
    }
```

Am I missing something here or is there something wrong with the `WebElement` -> `TestObject` conversion? Also is this possible using only TestObject or only WebElement? If I could get child  `TestObjects` containing certain attributes from a parent `TestObject` then I wouldn't need to make a mess using `WebElements`.

**Edit**

Another image of the HTML, this time with the first radio button checked. As you can see the second radio button no longer has the 'checked' attribute.

[image: HTML2]

Comment: @DebanjanB I did ask that, I am trying to get the TestObject with the attribute: 'checked' as you can see from the HTML I provided, only 1 radio button has a 'checked' attribute at a time, and that is the one I want to get.

Comment: Perhaps _Selenium-Java_ clients doesn't have **TestObject** which is well supported in _Katalon_. Hence the counter question.

Comment: @DebanjanB I am actually using _Katalon Studio_, and the reason I use **WebElement** is because I could not find a way to get child elements with **TestObjects** and hence the need for converting back to **TestObjects** once I have the **WebElement** I need

Comment: If I have got your question correctly, you are trying to get the **TestObject** which is having the `checked` attribute which is _Katalon_ specific. If getting the relevant _WebElement_ suffice to your need, update the question and I may construct an answer for this question.

Comment: @DebanjanB that is exactly what I need, I want to get the **WebElement** that is currently checked, notice it can be either of the 2 radio buttons.

Comment: Additionally, you need to update the question with text based HTML instead of an image. Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by changing `(".//*")` to `(".//*[@checked='checked']")`

```
 parentWebElement.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@checked='checked']")
```

will find the element that has the attribute `checked = 'checked'`

Notice that a list is no longer needed as there can only be 1 checked radio button at a time.

**Implementation**

```
public TestObject getCheckedTestObjectFromParent(String parentID){
    WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()
    WebElement parentWebElement = driver.findElement(By.id(parentID))

    //there is only 1 checked child at a time, so there is no need for a list
    WebElement checkedChild = parentWebElement.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@checked='checked']"))

    //convert the WebElement to a TestObject and return
    return getTestObjectFromWebElement(checkedChild)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the *WebElement* that is currently `checked` you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  WebElement elem = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.a-toggle.a-toggle--anycase#config-src-laserunits  div[id^='config-src-laserunits-']>input.a-toggle__radio[checked]")));
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  WebElement elem = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='a-toggle a-toggle--anycase' and @id='config-src-laserunits']//div[starts-with(@id, 'config-src-laserunits-')]/input[@class='a-toggle__radio' and @checked]")));
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Xpath

```
"//input[@id='config-src-laserunits-wavnmradio' and @checked='checked']"
```

Example:

```
List<WebElement> children = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@id='config-src-laserunits-wavnmradio' and @checked='checked']"))
```

It should return size 1

**EDIT**

```
 List<WebElement> children = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@id='config-src-laserunits-wavnmradio']"));
            for (int i=0;i<children.size();i++)
            {
                if(children.get(i).getAttribute("checked")!=null)
                {
                    System.out.println("radio button is checked");
                }
            }
```

Comment: this won't work since 'config-src-laserunits-wavnmradio' will not always have the 'checked' attribute, if 'config-src-laserunits-freqthzradio' is selected, then that will have the 'checked' attribute

Comment: so the two input fields that I have, either one can have the 'checked' attribute at a time, and that is the one I am trying to get.

Comment: what are you looking after? Can you elaborate.My initial thought you want that selected radio xpath.

Comment: The code is for that only.it will return size 1 instead of 2 radio button.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood anything.

Comment: I am trying to get the radio button that is currently checked, the one that is checked will have a 'checked' attribute. My parent div: 'config-src-laserunits' has 2 child divs that each contain a radio button, I traverse over the children elements to be able to get the element that has the 'checked' attribute, but it seems to not work

Comment: If you try my xpath and give the condition children.size()=1 this will validate also.

Comment: it will not because it will only check 1 of the radio buttons, not both, and the one that it will check might have 'checked' attribute or it might not

Comment: I don't think you are understanding what I am saying, there are 2 radio buttons, the other one is 'config-src-laserunits-freqthzradio', when either of these buttons is selected, it will have a checked attribute, otherwise this attribute will not be there, what I am trying to do is find the one that has the checked attribute

Comment: Look at the second HTML I added, you will understand what I am talking about

Comment: @Zymeriath : I think that is what you after.Can you check my updated answer.

Comment: I got it fixed by changing (".//*") to (".//*[@checked='checked']")

Comment: If you see my edited answer that is the best way you should do.